# Shape integrity error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, vector, geopackage

I'm working with a vector layer (from a geopackage) which I would like to convert to a raster layer. However, when I convert it certain parts just disappear. If I scroll through the attribute table far enough (ca. 35000 shapes) the 'Failed to load data. Error: Shape Integrity Error' shows up.

I have tried to use the 'Repair Geometry' tool. For this, I have to convert the layer (from a gpkg to a shapefile) for it to work. During the converting to a shapefile it immediately loses some shapes.

How can I approach and solve this problem?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro

I managed to solve the problem in two ways. The first with help from @BERA. I converted it to a shapefile in QGIS and then opened it in ArcGIS Pro. This would indicate that the fault was created by ArcGIS working with gpkg.

However, I also requested the file again. When I loaded the new file immediately into ArcGIS Pro it worked as well! So this would indicate the error was in the file.

Conclusion: I'm not sure where my error originated. You can always try to convert it into QGIS first. If this doesn't work it probably is a corrupted file.

Comment: Sounds like the geopackage is corrupted? Can you request it again?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of it being corrupted as well. Thus I have requested it again, and I will probably receive it tomorrow. I hope that will work...

Comment: The geometries were lost *before* converting to shapefile.

Comment: I dont trust ArcGIS Pro with geopackages or PostGIS, I get the same error as you. Or sometimes no error but all features dont show up (very dangerous) Try converting it to shapefile or geojson in QGIS then open in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Compare what QGIS finds from the GeoPackage. If QGIS reads all the features try to create a ArcGIS bug report with your ESRI support. Validate the GeoPackage with https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/validate_gpkg.py, otherwise they say that the error is in the GPKG, not in ArcGIS. They may still say the same but  it may help with getting the bug report accepted.

Comment: @Niek did you ever get another export to try? I'm experiencing a similar issue. I have a shapefile that was exported from PostGIS via pgsql2shp that opens fine in QGIS, but the table won't open in ArcGIS Pro 2.8. Creating a geopackage from that shapefile w/ ogr2ogr throws ```Warning 1: A geometry of type MULTIPOLYGON is inserted into layer foo of geometry type POLYGON, which is not normally allowed by the GeoPackage specification, but the driver will however do it. ```